# Selenium grid only opens 4 to 5 sessions

Tags: java, selenium, configuration, grid, selenium-grid

I am using selenium grid and I have 3 machines allocated for the grid. My hub config is as follows:

```
{
  "port": 4444,
  "newSessionWaitTimeout": -1,
  "servlets": [],
  "prioritizer": "com.xxxx.xxxx.grid.xxxxxxx",
  "capabilityMatcher": "org.openqa.grid.internal.utils.DefaultCapabilityMatcher",
  "throwOnCapabilityNotPresent": true,
  "nodePolling": 5000,
  "cleanUpCycle": 5000,
  "timeout": 4000000,
  "browserTimeout": 600000,
  "maxSession": 30
}
```

and my nodeconfig is like this:

```
{
  "capabilities":
      [
        {
          "browserName": "firefox",
          "maxInstances": 10,
          "seleniumProtocol": "WebDriver"
        },
        {
          "browserName": "chrome",
          "maxInstances": 5,
          "seleniumProtocol": "WebDriver"
        },
        {
          "browserName": "internet explorer",
          "maxInstances": 1,
          "seleniumProtocol": "WebDriver"
        }
      ],
  "configuration":
  {
    "proxy": "org.openqa.grid.selenium.proxy.DefaultRemoteProxy",
    "maxSession": 10,
    "port": 5555,
    "host": "012.xxx.net",
    "register": true,
    "registerCycle": 5000,
    "hubPort": 4444,
    "hubHost": "012.xxx.net"
  }
}
```

and I did similar node configs on other two  machines. According to the setup, I should have 30 nodes activated. I tried to run 90 test suites in parallel and the machine acts perfectly normal(all the 30 nodes/browsers are utilized), but when I increased the number of test suites to 200 or more, the machine is using only 4-5 nodes/browser instances. Is there anything I am missing here. Any help is really appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: 'maxSession' AFAIK is applicable only to the nodes and NOT to the hub. So your node config says that a node wll support at the max 10 sessions. You mentioned you have 3 machines, but say you expect 30 nodes.. Does that mean that for every machine you are spawning 10 nodes ? It would be better if you could please help clarify your setup a bit more clearly.

Comment: yes, The three machines are connected to he hub, i mean every machine is spawning 10 nodes. So in my case, machine 012 acts as hub with 10 nodes on it and other 2 machines say 013 and 014 are connected to 012 machine, In the node config, the hub host is assigned to 012 machine. So when the execution starts, total of 30 nodes are available. Please let me know if you need any other information.

Comment: Every machine supporting 30 concurrent firefox executions.. To me that sounds like a choking config.. You might want to bring down either the number of maxInstances of Firefox or bring down the number of nodes such that not more than 15 firefox instances can run at a given point in time..

Comment: What version of Selenium are you on ? The recent versions of selenium I remember has gone through some refactoring in terms of distribution of tests among node. So you can try using 2.53 and see if that helps. There are a lot of factors that I still am not able to understand here.. such as how do you say that only 4-5 nodes are being used and the others are not ? Have you actively monitored the console of all the 30 nodes at the same time to conclude on this ?

Comment: Each machine can start only 10 firefox sessions at a time. I have 3 machines allocated with 10 firefox sessions(max instances) so with all the 3 machines together there will be 30 firefox browsers running 10 on each machine. And yes i was monitoring the console, and also the reports.

Comment: Let me get this straight.. For a given machine how many "java -jar selenium-standalone -role node" are you running ? For every such instance you will be having 10 firefox instances.. So with 3 machines.. assuming that you are running only 1 such command you would have 30 firefox concurrent run support.. But your original post says "According to the setup, I should have 30 nodes activated. I tried to run 90 test suites in parallel and the machine acts perfectly normal(all the 30 nodes/browsers are utilized)".. How can 90 tests run in parallel with this setup...

Comment: So here is the thing, this is how the "Selenium Grid" works, when I have say X num of suites and Y number of sessions/nodes/firefoxbrowsers assigned where X>Y, Y number of firefox instances are started on a machine(All the y num of instances of firefox must be used when x>y) in my case even though x>y, the y num of instances are not getting used when x is increased. Thanks for your time and help, I will try to figure it out if you still dont get my problem.

Comment: @KrishnanMahadevan If interested you can follow the issue link in testng here : https://github.com/cbeust/testng/issues/1077 This is a bug from testng framework itself.

Answer (score 0):

Each node require minimum 1gb memory, if your machine has 8gb, you can create 7 instance and 2 concurrent sessions.

```
Machine = 8gb RAM
Instance = 7 
MaxSessions = 3
So Total concurrent browser you can open is **21**.
```